# IBM Social Business Toolkit - no support for IBM Connections 5.5?

Tags: java, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm asking myself whether IBM Connections 5.5 is not supported by IBM SBT.

The version I use is "1.1.11.20151208-1200".

My test procedure is the following:

```
public static void testCreateCommunity() throws ClientServicesException {
    String g = Variables.aCommunityService.createCommunity( "TEST", "TESTDESCRIPTION", "public" );

    if (g.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println( "x0[Failed] Creating Community  has failed." );
    }
    else 
    {
      System.out.println( "Creating Community  successfully done." );
    }
}
```

This code does perfectly work in Connections 5.0 CR 3 , but does not work
in IBM Connections 5.5.

I always get:

> com.ibm.sbt.services.client.ClientServicesException: Request to url https://blabla.com/communities/service/atom/communities/my returned an error response 400:Bad Request HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 10:20:02 GMT, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains, X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block, X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only, X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0, Expires: Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, X-LConn-Auth: false, X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge, Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 10:20:02 GMT, Set-Cookie: LtpaToken2=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; Path=/; Domain=.blabla.com, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000H65mMCw0ijcsS5e19kYaAyB:1a9lvgg03; Path=/; HttpOnly, Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, Connection: close, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Language: de-DE]

Does anybody know whether IBM SBT generally supports Connections 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have similar issues in Communities (and Activities) use cases. Most of the functionality works fine, but you stumbled upon an issue that we also encountered.

For now we are using the REST API's to work around this.

I know we could contribute to the open source project, but that will take some time.

So I would say it generally supports 5.5, but in this specific case ...

Answer (score 1):

After running into the same issue I have found a way to add the header before the createCommunity() service call. In your case it would look like this:

```
Variables.aCommunityService.addDefaultHeader("Content-Type","application/atom+xml")
//Then create community
```

https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/issues/1772#issuecomment-239517941

HTH